# Cython: Workaround for nested typedefs

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to wrap some C++ code with Cython.

The c++ header file "graph.h" contains the following definition:

```
#include "Block.h"
template <typename graphtype> class Graph
{
public:
       typedef enum
       {
               SOURCE  = 0,
               SINK    = 1
       } termtype; // terminals
       typedef int node_id;
       typedef Block<double> Block_D;

       Graph()
}
```

I tried the following in "Graph.pyx":

```
cdef extern from "graph.h":
   cdef cppclass Graph[graphtype]:
       ctypedef int node_id
       ctypedef enum termtype:
           SOURCE
           SINK
       ctypedef Block<double> Block;
```

However, none of those work. I found that Cython might not support nested typedefs. If that's true, is there any workaround for this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Right off the bat: you should change `ctypedef Block<double> Block;` to `ctypedef Block[double] Block` – and then don’t be surprised if the Cython compiler balks because that line attempts to `typedef`-alias something recursively *ad infinitium*. You can always delete that line if you don’t need to use `Block` explicitly in your Cython code (remember that cython `extern` definitions don’t have to include *everything* from the header files they inspect, only what you need to use by name).

Answer (score 2):

I have gotten nested definitions to work using the `namespace` keyword, specifying the nested declaration. Like, if you have e.g. the following in a C++ header named `mystuff.hpp`:

```
namespace MyStuff {
    struct Outer {
        struct Inner {
            int value;
        };
        Inner member;
    };
}
```

… you can encython those structures like so:

```
cdef extern from "mystuff.hpp" namespace "MyStuff::Outer":
    cppclass Inner:
        int value

cdef extern from "mystuff.hpp" namespace "MyStuff":
    cppclass Outer:
        Inner member
```

… it reads more coherently if you actually have everything in C++-land wrapped in a namespace, as written (otherwise the second `cdef` has no `namespace` in its declaration, which looks wierder IMO).

I have a number of real-world currently-working examples of this: [one such example is here](https://github.com/fish2000/halogen/blob/master/halogen/ext/halide/function.pxd), [another one is here](https://github.com/fish2000/halogen/blob/master/halogen/ext/halide/module.pxd). The illustrated example code initially showed up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39629552/298171).