# Cython : exposing C++ classes with nested typedef (s)

Tags: c++, class, nested, cython, typedef

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382575/are-c-style-internal-typedefs-possible-in-cython) question/answer in stackoverflow, it is not possible to directly rewrite C++ nested typedefs in cython. I have such a problem and I don't know which is the right/optimal way to proceed.

Let me be more specific with an example. Below, you can find the content of two C++ files (one header.h and one .cpp) and of two corresponding cython files (one .pxd and one .pyx). In the C++ header file called `cpp_graph.h` you can see nested typedef declarations; for example, that corresponding to `Graph::iterator::nn_iterator`. **I don't know how to expose that in the corresponding `graph.pxd` file.** Or, in other words, I don't know what is the "official" or "standard" way to do it.

Some relevant information. If you check the cython wrapper for STL you can find nested typedefs. For example [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/utility.pxd) in the `utility.pxd` or [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/vector.pxd) in the `vector.pxd` file. However, those nested usages of `ctypedef` are used for template declarations only. **Is it the case that nested typedefs work for template declarations only in cython?**

The C++ header file:

```
// file : cpp_graph.h

#ifndef Included_cpp_graph
#define Included_cpp_graph

#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "to_string_patch.h"

#ifndef Defined_bint
#define Defined_bint
typedef int                                          bint;
#endif

class Graph {
    public:
        typedef std::set< int >                      t_nn;
        typedef std::set< int >::iterator            nn_iterator;
        typedef std::map< int , t_nn >               t_node_to_nn;    
        class iterator
        {
            // To iterate over nodes.
            friend class Graph;
            public:
                typedef iterator self_type;
                typedef int value_type;
                typedef int & reference;
                typedef int * pointer;                
                typedef t_node_to_nn::iterator map_iterator; 
                typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
                iterator( map_iterator map_it ) : _map_it( map_it ) { }
                self_type operator++()         { _map_it++; return *this;                  } // PREFIX
                self_type operator++(int junk) { self_type i = *this; _map_it++; return i; } // POSTFIX  
                value_type    operator*()  { return   ( * _map_it ).first;  } // Return the index "i"
                Graph::t_nn * operator->() { return & ( * _map_it ).second; } // Return a pointer to the contained t_nn.
                bool operator==( const self_type & rhs ) { return _map_it == rhs._map_it; }
                bool operator!=( const self_type & rhs ) { return _map_it != rhs._map_it; }
            private:
                map_iterator _map_it;
        };    
        class const_iterator
        {
            friend class Vertex;        
            public:
                typedef const_iterator self_type;
                typedef int value_type;
                typedef int & reference;
                typedef int * pointer;                
                typedef t_node_to_nn::iterator map_iterator;
                typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
                const_iterator( map_iterator map_it ) : _map_it( map_it ) { }
                self_type operator++()         { _map_it++; return *this;                  } // PREFIX
                self_type operator++(int junk) { self_type i = *this; _map_it++; return i; } // POSTFIX 
                const value_type    operator*()  { return   ( * _map_it ).first;  } // Return the index "i"
                const Graph::t_nn * operator->() { return & ( * _map_it ).second; } // Return a pointer to the contained t_nn.
                bool operator==( const self_type& rhs ) { return _map_it == rhs._map_it; }
                bool operator!=( const self_type& rhs ) { return _map_it != rhs._map_it; }
            private:
                map_iterator _map_it;
        };     
        iterator begin() { _node_to_nn.begin(); }
        iterator end()   { _node_to_nn.end();   }        
        const_iterator begin() const { _node_to_nn.begin(); }
        const_iterator end()   const { _node_to_nn.end();   }        
        nn_iterator nn_begin( int i ) { assert( has_node( i ) ); return _node_to_nn[ i ].begin(); }
        nn_iterator nn_end( int i )   { assert( has_node( i ) ); return _node_to_nn[ i ].end();   }
        Graph() : _num_links( 0 ) {}
        ~Graph() { _node_to_nn.clear(); _num_links = 0; }
        Graph & subgraph( std::set< int > & nodes ) {
            Graph * S = new Graph();
            for ( std::set< int >::iterator n_it = nodes.begin() ; n_it != nodes.end() ; n_it++ ) {
                int i = ( * n_it );
                assert( has_node( i ) );
                for ( nn_iterator j_it = nn_begin( i ) ; j_it != nn_end( i ) ; j_it++ ) { 
                    int j = ( * j_it );
                    if ( nodes.count( j ) > 0 ) { S -> add_link( i , j ); }
                }
            }
            return ( * S );
        }
        int num_nodes() { return _node_to_nn.size(); }
        int num_links() { return _num_links; }
        int degree( int i )  { return _node_to_nn[ i ].size(); }
        double avrg_degree() { return ( ( double ) 2 * num_nodes() ) / ( ( double ) _num_links ); }
        bool has_node( int i ) { return _node_to_nn.count( i ) > 0; }
        bool has_nn( int i , int j ) { 
            if ( has_node( i ) ) { return _node_to_nn[ i ].count( j ) > 0; }
            return false;
        }
        bool has_link( int i , int j ) { return has_nn( i , j ); }
        void add_node( int i ) { _node_to_nn[ i ].count( 0 ); } // Trick...
        void add_link( int i , int j ) { 
            if ( has_link( i , j ) ) { return; }
            _node_to_nn[ i ].insert( j );
            _node_to_nn[ j ].insert( i );
            _num_links += 1;
        }
        void del_link( int i , int j ) {
            if ( has_link( i , j ) ) { 
                _node_to_nn[ i ].erase( j );
                _node_to_nn[ j ].erase( i );
                _num_links -= 1;
            }
        }
        void del_node( int i ) { 
            iterator i_it = _node_to_nn.find( i ); 
            for( nn_iterator j_it = i_it -> begin() ; j_it != i_it -> end() ; j_it++ ) { del_link( i , ( * j_it ) ); }
            _node_to_nn.erase( i_it._map_it );
        }
        void clear_node( int i ) { del_node( i ); add_node( i ); } // Trick...
    private:
        t_node_to_nn    _node_to_nn;
        int             _num_links;
};

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os , Graph & G );

typedef Graph::t_nn Graph_t_nn
typedef 

#endif // Included_cpp_graph
```

The C++ .cpp file:

```
// cpp_graph.cpp

#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "to_string_patch.h"
#include "cpp_graph.h"

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os , Graph & G ) {    
    os << "Graph{";
    // Print nodes.
    for ( Graph::iterator i_it = G.begin() ; i_it != G.end() ; i_it++ ) {
        int i = ( * i_it );
        os << " " << patch::to_string( i );
    }
    os << " |";
    // Print edges.              
    for ( Graph::iterator i_it = G.begin() ; i_it != G.end() ; i_it++ ) {
        int i = ( * i_it );
        for ( Graph::nn_iterator j_it = G.nn_begin( i ) ; j_it != G.nn_end( i ) ; j_it++ ) {
            int j = ( * j_it );
            if ( i < j ) { os << " " + patch::to_string( i ) << ":" << patch::to_string( j ); }
        }
    }
    os << " }"; // << std::endl;
    return os;
}   

// === For testing purposes ===.
/*
int main() {

    Graph G;   
    G.add_link( 1 , 2 );
    G.add_link( 1 , 3 );
    G.add_link( 2 , 3 );
    G.add_link( 3 , 4 );
    G.add_link( 4 , 5 );                
    G.add_link( 4 , 6 );
    G.add_link( 5 , 6 );            
    std::cout << G << std::endl;

    G.del_link( 3 , 4 );
    std::cout << G << std::endl;    

    G.del_node( 3 );
    std::cout << G << std::endl;    

    G.clear_node( 2 );
    std::cout << G << std::endl;    

    G.add_link( 100 , 101 );
    std::cout << G << std::endl;    
    std::cout << "N = " << G.num_nodes() << " M = " << G.num_links() << std::endl;        

}
*/
```

The cython .pxd file:

```
# file : graph.pxd

# === Cython cimports ===

from libcpp cimport bool
from libcpp.set cimport set as cset
from libcpp.map cimport map as cmap
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref, preincrement as inc

# === Exposing the C++ Graph class ===

cdef extern from "cpp_graph.h":
    cdef cppclass Graph:
        #public:
        ctypedef cset[ int ]                     t_nn
        ctypedef cset[ int ].iterator            nn_iterator
        ctypedef cmap[ int , t_nn ]              t_node_to_nn
        cppclass iterator:
            #friend class Graph;
            #public:
            typedef iterator self_type
            typedef int value_type
            typedef int & reference
            typedef int * pointer
            typedef t_node_to_nn::iterator map_iterator
            typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category
            iterator( map_iterator map_it )
            self_type operator++()
            self_type operator++(int junk)
            value_type    operator*()
            Graph::t_nn * operator->()
            bool operator==( const self_type & rhs )
            bool operator!=( const self_type & rhs )
            #private:
            #    map_iterator _map_it;
        cppclass const_iterator:
            #friend class Vertex;        
            #public:
            typedef const_iterator self_type
            typedef int value_type
            typedef int & reference
            typedef int * pointer               
            typedef t_node_to_nn::iterator map_iterator
            typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category
            const_iterator( map_iterator map_it )
            self_type operator++()
            self_type operator++(int junk)
            const value_type    operator*()
            const Graph::t_nn * operator->()
            bool operator==( const self_type& rhs )
            bool operator!=( const self_type& rhs )
            #private:
            #    map_iterator _map_it;
        iterator begin()
        iterator end()
        const_iterator begin() const
        const_iterator end()   const
        nn_iterator nn_begin( int i )
        nn_iterator nn_end( int i )
        Graph()
        ~Graph()
        Graph & subgraph( std::set< int > & nodes )
        int num_nodes()
        int num_links()
        int degree( int i )
        double avrg_degree()
        bool has_node( int i )
        bool has_nn( int i , int j )
        bool has_link( int i , int j )
        void add_node( int i )
        void add_link( int i , int j )
        void del_link( int i , int j )
        void del_node( int i )
        void clear_node( int i )
        #private:
            #t_node_to_nn    _node_to_nn;
            #int             _num_links;

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os , Graph & G )

# === Python Wrapper for the C++ Graph class ===

cdef class PyGraph:

    # === Data-members ===

    # Pointer to a C++ Graph object.
    cdef Graph * _c_graph

    # === Function-members ===    

    # @ graph.pyx
```

And the cython .pyx file:

```
# file : graph.pyx

# === Cython cimports ===

from libcpp cimport bool
from libcpp.set cimport set as cset
from libcpp.map cimport map as cmap
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref, preincrement as inc

# === Ctypedefs for Graph class ===

# @ graph.pxd

# === Exposing the C++ Graph class ===

cdef extern from "cpp_graph2.h":
    cdef cppclass Graph:
        #public:
        ctypedef cset[ int ]                     t_nn
        ctypedef cset[ int ].iterator            nn_iterator
        ctypedef cmap[ int , t_nn ]              t_node_to_nn
        cppclass iterator:
            #friend class Graph;
            #public:
            typedef iterator self_type
            typedef int value_type
            typedef int & reference
            typedef int * pointer
            typedef t_node_to_nn::iterator map_iterator
            typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category
            iterator( map_iterator map_it )
            self_type operator++()
            self_type operator++(int junk)
            value_type    operator*()
            Graph::t_nn * operator->()
            bool operator==( const self_type & rhs )
            bool operator!=( const self_type & rhs )
            #private:
            #    map_iterator _map_it;
        cppclass const_iterator:
            #friend class Vertex;        
            #public:
            typedef const_iterator self_type
            typedef int value_type
            typedef int & reference
            typedef int * pointer               
            typedef t_node_to_nn::iterator map_iterator
            typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category
            const_iterator( map_iterator map_it )
            self_type operator++()
            self_type operator++(int junk)
            const value_type    operator*()
            const Graph::t_nn * operator->()
            bool operator==( const self_type& rhs )
            bool operator!=( const self_type& rhs )
            #private:
            #    map_iterator _map_it;
        iterator begin()
        iterator end()
        const_iterator begin() const
        const_iterator end()   const
        nn_iterator nn_begin( int i )
        nn_iterator nn_end( int i )
        Graph()
        ~Graph()
        Graph & subgraph( std::set< int > & nodes )
        int num_nodes()
        int num_links()
        int degree( int i )
        double avrg_degree()
        bool has_node( int i )
        bool has_nn( int i , int j )
        bool has_link( int i , int j )
        void add_node( int i )
        void add_link( int i , int j )
        void del_link( int i , int j )
        void del_node( int i )
        void clear_node( int i )
        #private:
            #t_node_to_nn    _node_to_nn;
            #int             _num_links;

# === Python Wrapper for the C++ Graph class ===

cdef class PyGraph:

    # === Data-members ===    

    # @ graph.pxd

    # === Function-members ===    

    def __cinit__( self ):

        self._c_graph = new Graph()

    def __dealloc__( self ):

        del self._c_graph

    # TODO : implement the methods for adding and deleting nodes/links.
```

Finally, when I attempt to compile/build this, I get the following error:

```
###########################################################
# setup build_ext...
###########################################################

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
# === Exposing the C++ Graph class ===

cdef extern from "cpp_graph2.h":
    cdef cppclass Graph:
        #public:
        ctypedef cset[ int ]                     t_nn
       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

ExcessDegreeModel/graph.pxd:51:8: Expected an identifier, found 'ctypedef'
...
```

Comment: I think nested typedefs are only allowed in cython master branch (i.e., will be available in cython 0.25 when it's released): https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/CHANGES.rst

Comment: This specific error can be resolved by moving the `ctypedef`s up to the module level of the .pyx file structure – in other words put `ctypedef cset[int] t_nn` outside and above the `cdef extern`/`cppclass Graph` block. The template type `cset` is, after all, available globally throughout your .pyx file and not nested – the fact that there is a lexically analogous `typedef` in the header file you are looking at makes no difference in this case (you don”t have to specify everything in the header when writing cython `extern` definitions).

Comment: Thanks both for the useful information. Eventually, I have figured out the solution mentioned by @fish2000 in the comment and is the one I am implementing it now. However, the solution mentioned below seems the most appropriate.

Comment: You are welcome – glad to be of use, indeed. You will probably want to use the `namespace` tactic to declare those inner iterator structures you have – which of course you will, at minimum, have to change all instances of `typedef` to `ctypedef` or something similar. Most likely you can define the iterator structures with only the methods and/or operators you will literally invoke from Cython, omitting much or all of the C++ boilerplate.

Comment: Yes, I am attempting it now and I have one question. Is a `ctypedef` statement allowed under the scope of a `cdef extern ...`? If that is not possible, how do you use the `namespace` "tactic" to define the nested `typedef`s?

Comment: Basically: get rid of all of the typedefs except those you need to use from Cython. Then, of those remaining: don’t nest the typedefs at all, put them all at package-level. You can see one such typedef in the first example link I posted below. In many cases it’s easier to get rid of them (if they are dependent typenames within a template i.e. STL iterator typedefs)… You are trying to build your `pxd` subtractively, by starting with everything from the include file; but Cython `pxd` files are better built additively: put in what you need and not more. Trust me, I learned that the hard way, haha

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It agrees with which I was suspecting: **nested typedef definitions do not work for the moment; we have to re-define the hierarchies of typedef by "explicitly mentioning the whole path" for each statement**. Regarding the redundancy of cython's redefinitions in my code, I agree with you also. Most definitions/members are not needed and can be avoided. I am also learning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have gotten nested definitions to work using the `namespace` keyword, specifying the nested declaration. Like, if you have e.g. the following in a C++ header named `mystuff.hpp`:

```
namespace MyStuff {
    struct Outer {
        struct Inner {
            int value;
        };
        Inner member;
    };
}
```

… you can encython those structures like so:

```
cdef extern from "mystuff.hpp" namespace "MyStuff::Outer":
    cppclass Inner:
        int value

cdef extern from "mystuff.hpp" namespace "MyStuff":
    cppclass Outer:
        Inner member
```

… it reads more coherently if you actually have everything in C++-land wrapped in a namespace, as written (otherwise the second `cdef` has no `namespace` in its declaration, which looks wierder IMO).

I have a number of real-world currently-working examples of this: [one such example is here](https://github.com/fish2000/halogen/blob/master/halogen/ext/halide/function.pxd), [another one is here](https://github.com/fish2000/halogen/blob/master/halogen/ext/halide/module.pxd).

Comment: both example are dead.  I wonder if you wouldn't mind either in lining a full example or updating the links.

Comment: @Jzl5325 Fixed ‘em, thanks – I had gone on to reorganize that projects’ directory structure. If the contrived example is lacking something specific, let me know and I’ll add to it as well.